# Is it possible to group by multiple columns (OR statement) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

I'd like to group by 2 columns but in "or mode"... I think I'll explain myself better with an example:

```
ID  |  Col 1  |  Col 2  |   Col 3  | Rest of columns ...
-------------------------------------------------------
1        A         Q         green
2        B         R         blue
3        B         S         red
4        C         T         purple
5        D         U         orange
6        E         R         black
7        F         U         brown
8        F         V         pink
9        G         W         white
```

So ...
Grouping by column 1 we have rows 2+3 and 7+8 merged in results
Grouping by column 2 we have rows 2+6 and 7+5 merged in results

But I'd like to group between them, so the SQL results (in this case) in 2 rows in output:

1. rows 2, 3 and 6 in a group
2. rows 5, 7, and 8 in other group
3. among other unique rows

Visual explanation of the 1) group:
[image]

Visual explanation of the 2) group:
[image]

Is this possible in a unique SQL ? Or is it better to handle this data "merging" in programming code ?

So the result selecting a concat of the column 3, could be:

```
blue,red,black
brown,pink,orange

(and then the rest that are "unique" of the two groupings...)
green
purple
white
```

So it's like a "by group" but taking in account 2 columns :-P
It's difficult to explain, but I hope visual examples talk by their own.

BTW: I'm in MySQL 8 ... no matter which one, if I have to upgrade or change, I can do it ;-)

Comment: Use a CTE and then UNION them.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Also, you haven't told us how we should know which column (`Col1` or `Col2`) should be used for a any given row.

Comment: "Grouping by column 1 we have rows 2+3 and 7+8" - no, doing a `GROUP BY Col1` will give you `( 1, 2+3, 4, 5, 6, 7+8, 9 )`, not `( 2+3 )` - or do you want an implicit `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2`?

Comment: What do the values in your proposed grouping of rows have in common? I can't tell from your question how you know to group 5,7, and 8 together.

Comment: show  a complete [mre] and the endresult that you want. the exact version helps also

Comment: Hi @FlamingMoe please provide your sample output.

Comment: @nbk  edited to answer everything you said ;-)

Comment: @Dai  edited to answer everything you said ;-)

Comment: This would need arrays, which mysql doesn't support,, so do it in a stored procedure or in another language

Comment: Why is black grouped twice in your expected results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this sample data you can use a self join:

```
SELECT t1.col1, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(t2.col3) col3
FROM tablename t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2
ON t2.id = t1.id OR t2.col2 = t1.col2
GROUP BY t1.col1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t1.id) > 1 OR COUNT(t2.id) = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=55ea175fe87d5079a5cf50250aa2bc91).
Results:

| col1 | col3 |
| --- | --- |
| A | green |
| B | blue,red,black |
| C | purple |
| F | orange,brown,pink |
| G | white |

I guess it is a typo in your expected results.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description and end result

You can use this.

With additional subqueries you can make it you can gather more information as it is needed

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab1 (
>   `ID` VARCHAR(35),
>   `Col 1` VARCHAR(35),
>   `Col 2` VARCHAR(35),
>   `Col 3` VARCHAR(35)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tab1
>   (`ID`, `Col 1`, `Col 2`, `Col 3`)
> VALUES
>   ('1'        ,'A'         ,'Q' ,        'green'),
>   ('2'        ,'B'         ,'R'   ,     'blue'),
>   ('3'   ,     'B',         'S',         'red'),
>   ('4'  ,      'C',         'T' ,        'purple'),
>   ('5'        ,'D'        , 'U'     ,    'orange'),
>   ('6'      ,  'E'         ,'R'         ,'black'),
>   ('7'        ,'F'      ,  'U' ,        'brown'),
>   ('8'       ,'F'       ,  'V' ,        'pink'),
>   ('9',        'G ',        'W'      ,   'white');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> `Col 1`, col2
> , CONCAT(col3,',', (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`Col 3`) FROM tab1 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`Col 2`,col2) AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(`Col 3`,col3)))
>
> FROM (SELECT `Col 1`, GROUP_CONCAT(`Col 2`) as col2, GROUP_CONCAT(`Col 3`) col3 
> FROM tab1 
> GROUP BY `Col 1` 
> HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t1
> UNION
> SELECT `Col 1`, `Col 2`, `Col 3`
> FROM tab1
> GROUP BY `Col 2`
> HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> Col 1 | col2 | CONCAT(col3,',', (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`Col 3`) FROM tab1 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`Col 2`,col2) AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(`Col 3`,col3)))
> :---- | :--- | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> B     | R,S  | blue,red,black                                                                                                              
> F     | U,V  | brown,pink,orange                                                                                                           
> A     | Q    | green                                                                                                                       
> B     | S    | red                                                                                                                         
> C     | T    | purple                                                                                                                      
> F     | V    | pink                                                                                                                        
> G     | W    | white
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=7d00d371121d72b38d9904a244c15e21)*